# How i can get Response in String from Byte

Tags: android

i use AsyncHttpResponseHandler and i have this method:

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode,
            org.apache.http.Header[] headers,
            byte[] responseBody) {

        showProgress(false);



    }
```

But now, how i can get a response in String from byte array ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

And if you're feeling lazy, you can use the Apache Commons IO library to convert the InputStream to a String directly:

```
String str = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Working perfectly: String str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");